# adding CSS class to link dynamically

Tags: php

Can anybody tell me how can I add a css class to this links when click on it?

This is my links :

```
echo '<li><a href="?tutor=link&subject='.urlencode($subject).'">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a href="?institute=link&subject='.urlencode($subject).'">Institute</a></li>';
```

My problem is how I identify which link is clicked by users?

Comment: you should accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to add a class to a link if it is the current link being viewed.

Since each link has a different GET parameter you could use that to identify it.

```
echo '<li><a '. (isset($_GET['tutor']) ? 'class="current"' : '') .' href="?tutor=link&subject='.urlencode($subject).'">Tutor</a></li>
      <li><a '. (isset($_GET['institute']) ? 'class="current"' : '') .' href="?institute=link&subject='.urlencode($subject).'">Institute</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using javascript or jquery

```
$(this).css('newclassname')
```

thats the example of jquery

**updated**
you can bind it to a function to get the hold of the clicked element
        `$('a').click(function() {
            $(this).css('current');

            alert($(this).html()); // this will pop up tutor if its clicked
        });`

Comment: how I identify which like is clicked or which one is not clicked

Comment: if user click on 'Tutor' link then I need to add 'class="current" on to <a> tag

Comment: @TharangaNuwan - I have shown you how to achieve this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pure JavaScript solution you could do:

```
<a id="tutor" href="?tutor=link&subject='.urlencode($subject).'" onclick="changeClass(this)">Tutor</a>


function changeClass(link) {
    if (link.id == "tutor") {
       link.className = "current";
    } 
}
```

**Edit:**

You can identify which link was clicked by the `link` variable passed into the `changeClass` function.  The link variable will include an `id` property which will tell you the identifier of the `a` tag.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan - check my update, it should answer your question fully.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan - just have